# How  "click" function controls two image state

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, mouseclick-event

I have a music player in my site, here is the code:

```
<!-- player -->
<div id="player">
        <div class="playerIcon"><img src="../img/musicIcon.gif" alt="" width="21" height="19" border="0"></div>

        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="30" height="30" id="player1">
           <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="audioplay.swf?playerid=1">
           <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
           <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE="transparent">
           <PARAM NAME="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <embed wmode="transparent" src="audioplay.swf?playerid=1" quality=high width="30" height="30" name="player1" allowScriptAccess="always"
            align="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
         </object>

        <script language="javascript">
function getPlayer(movieName){
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName];} 
    else {
        return document[movieName];
        }
    }
function play1() {
    getPlayer('player1').playMusic();
}

function stop1(){
     getPlayer('player1').stopMusic();
    }
      </script> 
</div>
<!-- end player -->
```

Here, **player1** has its own icon and also on-off state when click to pause music. I'd like to change also animated **musicIcon.gif** img to non-animated one when i click player icon. How can i do this?
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a click listener on the *object* element? When called, it should look at the state of the movie and if it's stopped, replace `<img src="..." ...>` with the static image. If it's running, use the animated one.

You could also have both images in the page already and just toggle their *.style.display* property between *'none'* and *''* (empty string).